# Inserting + 4500 items with 7 columns each into SQlite Database with Retrofit2

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit2

I am working on an Android App for handheld Scan Devices and want to download around 4.500 items from an MySQL database via Retrofit2 into a SQlite Database on the device; hence, when I tried to download all items at once, it slowed down the UI and froze the app up to 5 minutes; I googled a lot on how to solve the problem and couldn´t come up with a fitting solution for now; hence I tried to download the Database with 7 columns for each item - hence, around 31.500 entries in the database - in "Chunks" by iterating in a For-each loop and using .stream() and .limit() in a Background threat, like this:

```
 public static void writeItemsToDatabase(Context mContext, String basic) {

        //creating the itemApi interface
        ItemApi itemApi = retrofit.create(ItemApi.class);

        //making the call object
        Call<List<Item>> call = itemApi.checkItems(basic);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Item>> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<List<Item>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Item> itemList;
                    itemList =  response.body();
                    int dataSize = response.body().size();
                    Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(dataSize));
                    itemList.forEach(List -> Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(List.getEan())));
                    itemList.forEach(List -> Log.d(TAGGG, String.valueOf(List.getNo())));
                    class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

                        // Runs in UI before background thread is called
                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            // Do something like display a progress bar
                        }

                        // This is run in a background thread
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            // Do something that takes a long time, for example:
                            for (int i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
                                try (DatabaseHandler itemsManager = new DatabaseHandler((XXXXApp)
                                        mContext.getApplicationContext())) {
                                    itemList.stream().limit(1500).forEach(item -> {
                                        itemsManager.addItem(item);
                                        itemsManager.close();
                                    });
                                }
                                // Call this to update your progress
                                publishProgress(i);
                            }
                            return "this string is passed to onPostExecute";
                        }

                        // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
                        @Override
                        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                            // Do things like update the progress bar
                        }
                        // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
                        }
                    }
                    new DownloadTask().execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Item>> call, Throwable t) {}
        });
        return;
    }
```

however, the result is not satisfying as the Database doesn´t get´s downloaded properly; I changed the values for i to 9 and .limit() to 500 (to achieve the same result, the Download of +4.500 Items) with the same result.

The problem certainly is in this code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
     try (DatabaseHandler itemsManager = new DatabaseHandler((XXXApp)
          mContext.getApplicationContext())) 
   {
         itemList.stream().limit(1500).forEach(item -> {
         itemsManager.addItem(item);
         itemsManager.close();
         });
         }
   // Call this to update your progress
publishProgress(i);
```

}

It is the nearest approach that I´ve found to what I want to achieve after googling a lot; the problem certainly is that it´s a For-Loop that closes the Database each time and reopens it; I am also not sure if the amount of Data is too big for an SQlite database; hence any help or hints on how to solve this properly would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Open the database *once*. Start a transaction. Insert all your data. Commit the transaction. (I have no idea how this translates to Android's (rather poor from what I've seen) sqlite bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Create once instance of DatabaseHandler(what is it? you can use room with more comfortable API) and reuse it](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#WriteDbRow).
2. [Insert](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#WriteDbRow) many(100-500) items in one [transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#public-methods_1).

Or you can create sqlite db file on server side then download it and open as DB in android app.